# The geometrical-locus result of collision and fall

Tags: classical-mechanics, collision

A classical momentum-conservation experiment follows about this way:

On a table there is a sloped track and a ball is rolled down. At the bottom of the track, a second ball is at rest. The balls collide and fall down to the floor. On the floor, a paper and carbon-paper are laid to record the position where the balls hit the floor.
[image: Momentum-conservation experiment setup]
The question is this: If the two balls have the same mass, and the experiment is repeated with varying collision-angle, what is the locus of the printed dots?  My calculations resulted in a cardioid for the hitting ball and a circle for the ball being hit and I'm doubtful that I made the calculations right.

Comment: Please show your solution.

Comment: shouldn't be cardioid for the hitting ball, as the ball can't go backwards, but only at an angle $90^0 - 0^0$  with respect to the forward direction.